# Measuring distance at angle

Tags: measurement, distance

I have a question, I want to measure a distance from an object of unknown shape and material, and I want to measure it under different angles, I want to measure a distance to just one specific point of object and accuracy has to be good.

Can someone please point me to right direction?

Comment: Not the right place to ask this question, please ask at robotics forum.Its very unlikely to get answer here.

Comment: Ok, tnx for informing me

Comment: Well, you can measure a 380 000 km distance with a 3 cm accuracy, will that do? I mean: what distance range and what accuracy are you thinking of? (The 3 cm accuracy is for measuring the distance earth-moon with a laser, it that would help.)

Comment: from 1cm to 50cm witch accuary down to 1mm

Comment: Laser inferometry?

Comment: @pjc50, laser interferometers are very good at measuring how far something moved (like sub-micron accuracy); but not so great for measuring the absolute distance without some starting reference point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard laser rangefinder (I have a Bosch DLE70) can give you 1.5mm precision from 5cm to many meters (mine works up to 70 meters) and works in daylight and for every texture and object I've tried.

Also look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsnzorA0WSs)

Comment: Tnx, I will check the video when i am at home, btw: how fast can it measure?

Comment: DLE70 have a function that gives you a continuous distance reading, and IIRC it refresh display in less than a second. I can do a test tonight if you like, it's a function than I usually don't use.

Comment: Can you please do the test and contact me over luka.pivk[at]avspekter.si. Tnx!

Comment: Done and mail sent. But I also report the results here. in my tests measures in the range 10cm-2m always took less than 0.7 seconds.